Plugging External Hard Drives in USB Blocks Raspberry Pi Access
When I plug my (powered) external hard drive (any of several that I have) into my Pi USB ports I cannot log into Raspberry Pi (ssh). If I unplug the external hard drive I can log in, and then I can plug in the drive. Then I can (with difficulty) mount it as a Raspberry Pi directory (e.g., sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home/pi/g). I must unplug the drive before a reboot.
Obviously automatic mounting (fstab) doesn't work since the drives can't be hooked up for a reboot.
How do I configure my raspberry pi 5 so that it will allow me to log in (ssh) when the external drives are attached to the Pi usb ports?
More information:
I had 4 external drives each with 2 partitions hooked up to a Raspberry Pi 4 on Verizon and it worked great for years. I moved and had to switch to Xfinity, and my same setup would not get recognized as a connected device. I purchased Pi 5 to start over. Xfinity recognized my Pi 5 as a connected device, but not with the drives attached.
For the install on Pi 5 I used imager_1.8.5 defaults, with the enable ssh option, then sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin. It was a headless install.

how do i log into my raspberry pi 5 using ssh when my external hard drive is plugged into the usb, obviously with the intent of automatically mounting the drive?

the question  belongs in your post, not in a comment ... please use the edit button, and add it there ... the comment can be deleted

I don't see how your internet provider is relevant to what is probably some weird power issue. I would recommend attaching a keyboard and monitor to the Pi so you can observe what happens when you plug the drive into Pi

don't have them, hence the headless installation.

Have you checked dmesg?
